# Vaadin 7 Vertical Layout

Tags: java, eclipse, vaadin

I am new to Vaadin 7 and try to recode the tutorial from the [Page](https://vaadin.com/tutorial).
Now i have some problems with Vaadin and Eclipse. I setup the Vaadin project as an Maven Project with dependencies to Vaadin 7.1.0
When I try to reference the `VerticalLayout` my Eclipse IDE can't find the import. It follows that Eclipse can't build the Project.

I've still checked the Java Libraries and find the correct Class in path. Maybe somebody knows this Problem and can help to perform the correct import.

Comment: how did you create the project? Did u use the vaadin eclipse plugin

Comment: No I used New... -> Maven Project -> vaadin-archtype-clean

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the [vaadin plugin for eclipse](https://vaadin.com/eclipse)
and give a try after adding it

Comment: I have installed the Vaadin Plugin, but I don't want to use the mechanism to create a new project with it (I don't want Ivy).

Comment: yes neither I want it , But I tried it as maven and works fine.